# VSTS - how to select local agent for Release definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are unable to run any release becouse of the following message:

```
Your account has no free minutes remaining. Add a hosted pipeline to run more builds or releases.
```

I guess this happend becouse one of our build was using the hosted version and not the private pipeline.

The problem now is that we cannot run any builds. The builds are running fine (on local agents) but we're unable to run any releases.

How can we modify the release definition to use a local agent?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It looks like it is described in point #7 of this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/work-with-release-definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose the agent queue to use for a release within the Phase view within an environment.

A release has environments. An environment can have multiple phases. Each phase can run on a different agent queue.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a licensing issue to me.  VSTS Release pipelines are a paid product.  You get 1 hosted and/or private pipeline free each month, but after that you pay for each one.  Hosted pipelines are also limited to the number of minutes you can execute them (You get 240 free minutes).

Check out [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/) for additional details and make sure you are licensed up.

Also, if you have Visual Studio Enterprise licenses, these will grant you extra pipelines per user.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was, specifically, "How do I choose an agent queue for a release?"